# Force binding update on DependencyProperty when internal field changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I bind to the same ClassXSource between multiple UserControls to have the data in sync between them. When the ClassXSource changes in one, the OnClassXSourceChanged is triggered in all. But this happens only if the the complete object is changed, and I am trying to force update between all DependencyProperties when a field within changes.

Example:

```
ClassXSource = new ClassX() { Field1 = "test" } //this will update binding in all
ClassXSource.Field1 = "test" //will not update other bindings
```

One of controls

```
<local:MyUserControl ClassXSource="{Binding ClassXSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainUserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

MyUserControl

```
public ClassX ClassXSource
{
    get { return (ClassX)GetValue(ClassXSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ClassXSourceProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ClassXSourceProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("ClassXSource", typeof(ClassX), typeof(MyUserControl),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnClassXSourceChanged)));

private static void OnClassXSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Class

```
public class ClassX 
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
}
```

Comment: In order to get the OnClassXSourceChanged callback called, the value of the property must change. In other words, it must be a new object - or the old one after temporarily setting a null value.

Answer (score -1):

`ClassX` needs to [implement change notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification). By implementing `INotifyProeprtyChanged` (or using dependency properties), objects with bindings to `ClassX` will be notified of changes and the bindings will update properly.

If you're not binding to properties of `ClassX` and want to handle property changes directly in the code-behind, you can attach a handler to the `PropertyChanged` event. You can do this in the `OnClassXSourceChanged` method.

Note that, either way, this only works with *proeprties*, not fields. You'll have to change `Field1` and `Field2` into properties, or add properties on top of them, if you want to bind to them.

Comment: This is not true. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in ClassX will not update a Binding of the ClassXSource property.

Comment: @Clemens True, but it will update all the objects that are bound to the changing property of the current `ClassXSource`, which should be enough to keep everything in sync.

Comment: It will exactly not do that. The control would at least have to attach a PropertyChanged event handler to the ClassX instance in its OnClassXSourceChanged callback.

Comment: @Clemens Ah, I just review the question. I thought he was binding to the proeprties of `ClassX`. You're right, it looks like he'll have to listen for changes with the event.